# Handling Duplicate Users In Flask and Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to allow anonymous users to post their comments in a blog without requiring them to login or sign up. One anonymous user can post several comments using the same credentials during subsequent visits. However, I get `SQLAlchemy IntegrityError` during a second attempt.

I have a simple form, a simple model and a basic route.

`comment.py`

```py
class CommentForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    comment = TextAreaField('Comment', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Post')
```

`models.py`

```py
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(500))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow) 
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

`route.py`

```py
@app.route('/personal_blog', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def personal_blog():
    form = CommentForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(username = form.username.data, email = form.email.data)        
        post = Post(body = form.comment.data, author = user)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your comment is now live!')  
        return redirect(url_for('personal_blog', _anchor='translate-hover'))  
    posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.timestamp.desc()).all()
    return render_template('personal_blog.html', form = form, posts = posts)
```

I have tried several suggested solutions and the closet I have come to was to add validation to the form, such as this:

```py
class CommentForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    comment = TextAreaField('Comment', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Post')

    def __init__(self, original_username, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CommentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.original_username = original_username

    def validate_username(self, username):
        if username.data != self.original_username:
            user = User.query.filter_by(username=self.username.data).first()
            if user is not None:
                raise ValidationError('Please use a different username.')
```

This, however, needs the addition of `@app.route('/personal_blog/<username>')` which essentially does not work for my case. I want to have this anonymous user post subsequent comments without the need of changing either *username* or *email*.

Personally, I have tried to add validation within the route (`if user.username is not None: flash('Use different credentials!')`) to notify the user that the email or username they are trying to use has already been used, and it works, but this is not what I want the app to do. The user can simply use the very same credentials as before. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is to remove the `unique` constraint from the `User` table.

Instead of:

```py
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True) <----------here
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True) <----------here
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
```

I have this:

```py
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True) <----------here
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True) <----------here
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
```

As soon as I update the database, the changes take effect and I am able to allow a single anonymous user to post more than one comment using the same credentials.